# give value of id to any column in insert query

Tags: php, mysql

**Description :**

I have an insert query that inserts data perfectly..

Now to keep track of record I have a product_id which is same as the id of the table which is auto increment

the method I am using is I get the last id in the table , increment it and assign the value to product_id.. It works perfectly but there is a bug in my code and that is when the table is empty there is no last id to fetch and increment ...

So by default it gets 0 , increments it to 1 and assigns the value to product id ...

this starts to work perfectly when the query is run again because the second time there actually is last id to fetch

So table looks something like this

what I want is

id  |  post_id

231 |    1

232 |   232

what I want is

id  |  post_id

231 |    231

232 |   232

So is there any way that I upon inserting the data could assign the value of id to product_id so they both are equal as if there were two auto increments ...
Anyone ??

Comment: you could use a post-insert trigger to do this, but why is this necessary? there's no point in wasting space for what is essentially a totally duplicated value.

Comment: Now that you have mentioned it ... I have made some stupid columns as id where it was never needed ... there are other columns in the tables that fit right to be the primry key ... thanks.. some times an answer is not what you are looking for ...